# Best Way to generate excel report

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2008, rdlc

Actually I'm asking this question because I want to know what is best solution for this base on what I only have. First let me show you what I really want to achieve. My boss want me to generate report in excel file (.xls or xlxs) then inside this report compose of multiple sheets with each respective sheet name. Data are presented in nice and professional way and sometime there are graphs inside that are link with the data within the sheet and it looks like this:[image]

Below is what I only have to generate this output.

- Visual Studio 2008
- Sql Server 2008 (no SSRS)
- Report is generated via
  RDLC (naming of sheet is not possible for this but multiple sheet is
  doable via pagebreak)
- I try to update excel file via Sql Server but
  seem too complicated for this specially when dealing with Total
  fields.
- I have not yet tried to render graph on .rdlc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the data lives in SQL server. If you have access to it, why not create an ODBC connection and use this to pull raw data into each one of the sheets you need, and then configure a dashboard tab that automatically pulls data from those sheets (even if you refresh it) and shows the graphs and summary tables in the format that you want?